# After installing Java 9, Eclipse getting crashed while opening In windows 10

Tags: eclipse, java-9, eclipse-oxygen

I have installed Java 9.
Command Prompt shows that my java path updated to version 9.
After installing and verifying my java version changes if i open my eclipse, it getting failed to open with a error.Below i have copied the error log.

Note : 
 - I have installed java 9 support plugin with my Eclipse but that also didn't help me.

```
  BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
    Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
    Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

    !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-09-28 11:39:12.220
    !MESSAGE Application error
    !STACK 1
    org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/PostConstruct
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:410)
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:318)
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:162)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createDefaultHeadlessContext(E4Application.java:491)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createDefaultContext(E4Application.java:505)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createE4Workbench(E4Application.java:204)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:614)
        at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:594)
        at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:151)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:653)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:590)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1499)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1472)
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/PostConstruct
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:124)
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:399)
        ... 23 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.annotation.PostConstruct cannot be found by org.eclipse.e4.core.di_1.6.100.v20170421-1418
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:433)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:387)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:150)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 25 more
```

Comment: can you share your eclipse.ini

Comment: Thanks for the immediate response from every one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure to [how to configure Eclipse for Java 9](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Configure_Eclipse_for_Java_9), specifically configuring the eclipse.ini file:

> Your eclipse.ini should contain something like:

```
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9\bin\javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
```

Comment: Thank you. I never had chance to use eclipse.ini. So i was never aware of it,after changing this it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the path to your -vm and and added ALL-SYSTEM modules?

E.g. in `eclipse.ini`

```
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9\bin\javaw.exe
...
...
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
```

https://wiki.eclipse.org/Configure_Eclipse_for_Java_9

Comment: Thanks , it worked for me